# How do I delete specific characters from a particular String in Java?

Tags: java, string, immutability

For example I'm extracting a text String from a text file and I need those words to form an array. However, when I do all that some words end with comma (,) or a full stop (.) or even have brackets attached to them (which is all perfectly normal).

What I want to do is to get rid of those characters. I've been trying to do that using those predefined String methods in Java but I just can't get around it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

```
String str = "whatever";
str = str.replaceAll("[,.]", "");
```

[replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  This:

```
[,.]
```

...looks for each comma and/or period.

Comment: thank you :)
I knew it wasn't something difficult, just couldn't get around it.

Comment: Too many characters in charter literal. How do I actually type this?

Answer (score 181):

Reassign the variable to a substring:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)
```

Also an alternative way of solving your problem: you might also want to consider using a [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to read the file and set the delimiters to be the characters you don't want to be part of words.

Comment: that's exactly what I did and it worked :)

BTW I forgot to mention that the use of StringTokenizer class was strictly forbidden by my mentor.

Comment: This micro-benchmark suggests that substring() may be faster than regex in this context: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/cf4e57a09eb8ff7c

Comment: @trashgod - you don't need a microbenchmark to tell you that.  Just a tiny amount of common sense ... and looking at the source code of `String.substring()`.

Answer (score 7):

To remove the last character do as [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962181/how-do-i-delete-the-last-character-of-a-particular-string-in-java/1962189#1962189) said

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
```

Additionally, another way to remove the characters you don't want would be to use the `.replace(oldCharacter, newCharacter)` method.

as in:

```
s = s.replace(",","");
```

and

```
s = s.replace(".","");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify a String in Java. They are immutable. All you can do is create a new string that is substring of the old string, minus the last character.

In some cases a StringBuffer might help you instead.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do something like this:
[code]
for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {

                if ((textArray[i].endsWith(",")) || textArray[i].endsWith("."))
                    textArray[i].substring(textArray[i].indexOf(textArray[i].length()-1));
               
                
                System.out.println(textArray[i].toLowerCase());

            }
[/code]

Answer (score 3):

The best method is what Mark Byers explains:

```
s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)
```

For example, if we want to replace \ to space " " with ReplaceAll, it doesn't work fine

```
String.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

or

```
String.replaceAll("\\$", "");   //if it is a path
```

Comment: I don't think it's a bad answer, but one thing it's not is INFALLLIBLE.  Try it on ""

Answer (score 0):

Note that the word boundaries also depend on the Locale. I think the best way to do it using standard java.text.BreakIterator. Here is an example from the java.sun.com tutorial.

```
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Locale;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "For example I'm extracting a text String from a text file and I need those words to form an array. However, when I do all that some words end with comma (,) or a full stop (.) or even have brackets attached to them (which is all perfectly normal).\n" +
            "\n" +
            "What I want to do is to get rid of those characters. I've been trying to do that using those predefined String methods in Java but I just can't get around it.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "Every help appreciated. Thanx";
    BreakIterator wordIterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    extractWords(text, wordIterator);
}

static void extractWords(String target, BreakIterator wordIterator) {
    wordIterator.setText(target);
    int start = wordIterator.first();
    int end = wordIterator.next();

    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
        String word = target.substring(start, end);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(0))) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        start = end;
        end = wordIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Source: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/text/word.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()` method :

```
String.replaceAll(",", "");
String.replaceAll("\\.", "");
String.replaceAll("\\(", "");
```

etc..

Comment: replaceAll will replace all the character not the last character only.