# java - removing semi colon from a string if the string ends with it

Tags: java, string

I have a requirement in which I need to remove the semicolon if it is present at the end of the String(only at the end). I have tried the following code. But still it is not getting replaced. Can anyone please tell what I need to change in the following code in the line number
(I referred the code from here [How do I delete specific characters from a particular String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962181/how-do-i-delete-the-last-character-of-a-particular-string-in-java))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "wherabouts;";
    System.out.println("SSS "+text.substring(text.length()-1));
    if(text.substring(text.length()-1) == ";"){
        text.replaceAll(";", "");
    }
    System.out.println("TEXT : "+text);
}
```

Comment: The character isn't replaced as clearly stated in his original post.

Comment: So many things are wrong here...

Comment: what if there are 2 semi colons at the end of string?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Since Strings in Java are immutable, so `replaceALl()` method doesn't do the in-place replacement, rather it returns a new modified string. So, you need to store the return value in some other string. Also, to match the *semi-colon* at the end, you need to use `$` quantifier after `;`

```
text = text.replaceAll(";$", "");
```

`$` denotes the end of the string since you want to replace the last `semi-colon`..

If you don't use `$`, it will replace all the `;` from your strings..

Or, for your job, you can simply use this, if you want to remove the last `;`:

```
    if (text.endsWith(";")) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

**UPDATE**: And, if there are more semi-colons at the end:

```
text = text.replaceAll(";+$", "");
```

Answer (score 18):

`String modifiedText = text.replaceAll(";$", "");`

**OR**

`text = text.replaceAll(";$", "");`

**OR**

```
if (text.endsWith(";")) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
}
```

***NOTE***:

Strings are immutable.  That means you can't change them.

Therefore you have to either re-assign *text* or set it to a new variable.

Comment: what s the $ sign at the end for? regex? endswith?

Comment: Correct, the `$` symbol represents _the end of input_ in a regex.  This typically helps to match a pattern that appears at the end of a line or the end of a string.  This causes `text.replaceAll(";$", "")` to replace only a semi-colon that appears as the last character.

Comment: Note that as @RohitJain has pointed out, if you want to deal with the possibility of multiple semi-colons at the end of the line, you can add a `+` symbol:  `text.replaceAll(";+$", "");`

Answer (score 4):

```
text = text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Here's a little extra reading for you
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html

Answer (score 3):

You should not forget that String is immutable. So, whenever you want to modify it, you have to assign the result to a variable.

A possible solution to what you need:

```
if (text.endsWith(";") {
  text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I believe the OP only wants to replace semi-colons at the end of the string.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for not down-voting.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in java are immutable, so `replaceAll` returns a new string.

Do

```
 text = text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.equals()` instead of `==` if you're going to use `substring()` rather than `charAt()`:

```
if(text.substring(text.length()-1).equals(";"))
```

Also, reassign your text variable:

```
text = text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Comment: You need a paren around the string after `equals`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  :)  Not that the OP needs more examples or answers at this point.  Haha

Comment: Can you please tell - what if there are 2 semi colons at the end of string?

Comment: All of them will be effectively erased from the String, since you are using `replaceAll()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (text.endsWith(";")){
    text = text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong version of `String.substring`, You could use:

```
text.substring(0, text.length() - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable so new String will be created after replace.

```
String newString = text.replace(";", "");
```

or

```
String newString = text.replaceAll(";$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in the code you have provided.

Use [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) to compare objects.

```
if(text.substring(text.length()-1).equals(";"))
```

If you want to replace only the last character, you dont need replaceAll.

So do either

```
if(text.substring(text.length()-1).equals(";")) {
      text = text.substring(0, text.length()-1);
    }
```

or

```
text = text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text_original = "wherabouts;";
    char[] c = text_original.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("TEXT original: "+ text_original);

    String text_new = c[text_original.length()-1] == ';' ? text_original.substring(0,text_original.length()-2) : text_original;

    System.out.println("TEXT new: "+text_new);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for only one semi-colon

```
// Don't use regular expressions if you don't need to.
if (text.endsWith(";")) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
}
```

Slower solution for possibly more than one semi-colon

```
text.replaceAll(";+$", "");
```

Additionally, here are some other problems with the code you originally posted, for reference.

```
if(text.substring(text.length()-1) == ";"){
```

You can't compare strings with `==`.  Instead, you have to compare them with `.equals()`.  This would be correctly written like this `...ength()-1).equals(";")`.

```
text.replaceAll(";", "");
```

This replaces all semicolons it finds.  This means that if your string was `some;thing;`, it would turn it into `something`, but you want to only remove the last semicolon, like this: `some;thing`.  To do this correctly, you need to look for the end of the string, using the special `$` character like this:

```
text.replaceAll(";$", "");
```