# Replacing last comma in a string

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java - removing semi colon from a string if the string ends with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806187/java-removing-semi-colon-from-a-string-if-the-string-ends-with-it)

"Dear $contact_name$,

Your job posting for $job_title$ has been submitted to the following job boards as
Free Job Boards        $Free_Job_Boards$, 
                                  $paid_job_boards$. 
Each job board can take up to 48 hours to process the request.

Thank you,

Here i want to remove comma after $Free_Job_Boards$ when there is no paid jobs.
when i use content=content.replaceAll(" ,","") then comma after $contact_name$ also removed

Comment: Look at the API documentation of `java.lang.String` and see if there are any methods in there that you can use for this.

Answer (score 8):

```
String s = "dsd,fsf,fsfsfsf,rwrw.com,ryriyry,hfhfhfh,";
if (s.endsWith(",")) {
    s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String str=" dsd,fsf,fsfsfsf,rwrw.com,ryriyry,hfhfhfh,";
    if(freeJob && str.endsWith(","))
        str=str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf(","));
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But actually str is  dsd,fsf,fsfsfsf,rwrw.com,ryriyry,hfhfhfh and last comma is used for adding paid job contents. But when there is only free job board,this comma is not needed. but it exist

Comment: then you can check availability of "," at the end of string and then replace it . like pap has posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(yourString);
b.replace(yourString.lastIndexOf(","), yourString.lastIndexOf(",") + 1, "" );
yourString = b.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the sub string, from `index 0` to the `last index` of `,`: -

```
String s = "whatever your String"; 
String s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(','));
```

Comment: "Dear $contact_name$, 

Your job posting for $job_title$ has been submitted to the following job boards as
Free Job Boards        $Free_Job_Boards$, 
                                  $paid_job_boards$. 
Each job board can take up to 48 hours to process the request.

Thank you, Here i want to remove comma after $Free_Job_Boards$ when there is no paid jobs.

Comment: That was a hint, for your specific scenario you can add a condition 
`if($paid_job_boards==null)`.